# What should be return value of a jar called from Makefile in case of failure?

Tags: java, makefile, jar, return-value

I have created a jar that has a main class and main method. So, I can execute the jar like `java -jar jarname.jar`.
Now, I am executing this jar from a Makefile. So, if the jar fails to do its purpose, Makefile should stop there and not continue. For this purpose, in the main method in jar, I'm returning 0 if success, and 1 if it fails. It is working perfectly as I expect. But my question is, is this the right way to do? Or is there a better way to do this? I think this is sufficient info, but in case you need extra info, I'm glad to provide.

Comment: Yes - the convention (which Makefile honours) is that success is an exit code of 0, failure is any other exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX) (which Make [understands](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors)) is that success is an exit status of 0, failure is any other exit status.